# How to efficiently make many (100+) HTML pages with minor differences

Tags: php, html, mysql, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make 100+ registration pages for my site with minor differences between each one.
For example:

State, Age, Start Date, Client Goal

Page 1 characteristics: California, Age 18-25, Start Date Dec 1, Goal 1

Page 2 characteristics: New York, Age 25-30, Start Date Dec 15, Goal 3

Page 3 characteristics: New Jersey, Age 18-25, Start Date Jan 1, Goal 2

**Goal:**

It's important that I have separate pages and not just a form or something selected by the user on a single page. Ultimately I'd like to have many more levels of customization than what I have above and would like to control all the pages without having to go in and edit each individually.

**Suggested Method:**

I was thinking I could make 1 PHP template and use it on every page to pull a unique code from the href to determine what data it gets from the database to display on the page.

To get my page 1 it would be something like:

`window.location.href`

returns -> mysite.com/CA-18-12-1-G1

Then use that code to set PHP variables which would customize the entire page just by echoing the html with the variables.

Is there a better/smarter/safer way?

I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: _..I could make 1 PHP template and use it on every page ..._ yes, do that, actually one **html** template which gets filled by php...there are also tons of tutorials and examples out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it this way: you want to make just one page, and you want to render it with 100+ different customizations.

Figure out the common HTML and CSS for your template page, and figure out what needs to change customization-by-customization. You'll have a set of customization parameters when you finish this design work.

Then, design some kind of data structure to hold your customization parameters. A table in MySql with one column for each parameter and one row for each of your 100 customizations might be a good way to do this.

Then write a php program to retrieve the row with the parameters for the customization you want, fill in your common HTML with the customizations, and send it to the browser for your user to fill in.

If you only need two or three custom pages, my advice would be to program them separately. But with 100 you need a template / parameter approach.

Answer (score 0):

For writing a single page and then using the code of that page in multiple pages you can use PHP.
Lets say you have a page named `constant.php`and you want to use the code of the page in a different PHP page named `home.php`. You have to use this code in the `home.php` where you want the code to be inserted:

```php
<?php include "constant.php";?>
```

Now the code of`constant.php` code will get inserted in the `home.php` in the place where you wrote this code.